# How to open two seperate nw.js apps

Tags: npm, package.json, node-webkit

I am building a server and a client nwjs app, but I can't open both at the same time. I wonder if there is any way to do this. I run `npm run dev` on both of my opened VS Code but when I run this command on the second app it just won't open at all (doesn't matter which one is the second app I would like to run). I tried to build the client app and run it and after it run the server app but it's the same, the second app won't start.

This is my package.json file in both app, I don't know if this helps at all. Only the name is different in the apps (nwjs_client and nwjs_server)

```
{
  "name": "nwjs_server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nw src/",
    "prod": "nwbuild --platforms win32,win64,osx64,linux32,linux64 --buildDir dist/ src/"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nw": "^0.49.1"
  }
}
```

I'm willing to accept any answers, I don't know if it is even possible to run 2 different nwjs apps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by what you are trying to do.

- If you are trying to run an NW.js that, instead of loading directly from a `index.html`, it loads displays a page from a local webserver:

  1. Create an `server.js` that spins up a local web server on a specific port (like `4263` or something not super common).
  2. If you need any node_modules for this (like `express`) make sure it is a `dependency` and not a `devDependency`.
  3. Set your `"main"` in the `package.json` to `"http://localhost:4263` using the same port as the server
  4. set your `"node-main"` to `"server.js"`, this will run in the node context before your window is displayed when starting the app.
  5. Set your `"node-remote"` to `"http://localhost:4263"` using the same port also. This will allow Node commands to run on that URL when loaded in NW.js.
- If you are wanting to run two commands at the same time you can:

  1. `npm install --save-dev concurrently wait-on`. This will install two devDeps
  2. Set your npm script to `"start": "concurrently \"npm run serve\" \"wait-on http://localhost:4263 && nw .\""`
  3. This will run your `npm run serve` command, which presumably spins up a local webserver for development, if using something like webpack, this could take a minute. Then it waits until `localhost:4263` actually returns a response. Then it launches NW.js

[concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) will also let you run any two (or more) commands at the same time.